Maximum points a round trip can get in a 2D grid
I am developing a snake-like game that involving solving the following problem:
Given an m*n 2D grid, some of the locations are one while other locations are zero. The snake starts at (0,0) and will head toward  the destination (m-1,n-1). At each step, it can only go right or down. Once it reached (m-1,n-1), it need to go back to (0,0) and in each step it can only go left or up. What is the maximum points it can get with this round trip?
If it is only an one-way trip, this can be easily solved with dynamic programming: max_gain(i,j)=max(max_gain(i+1,j),max_gain(i,j+1))+loc\[i\]\[j\]. However, in my problem, it is a round-trip and one the way back, we must exclude points that are already taken on the way towards the destination. The input size (m and n) are around 1K so it is not practical to brute force it.

If the snake can't make detours, (only right down first, then only up left) I think it's a simple calculation...

@Turo " it can only go right or down.

@ravenspoint Yeah, so either the snake can't go back, blocking the way on the first half or it can make something like 2*(m+n-2) points (depending how start and end counts), that's what I think

3 by 3 grid.  Going down 0,0->1,0->1,1->2,1->2,2.  Going back 2,2->1,2->0,2->0,1->0,0

What's the significance of the 1's and 0's in the grid? Is the snake only allowed to visit the 1's? The 0's? Seems to me if there is a path from (0,0) to (m-1,n-1) and the snake can only go right or left, then the number of moves along that path will always be m+n-2.

Assume visiting cell with 1 increments score by 1.

Round trip is the same as 2 single trips and now the question is, maximum points for 2 trips from (0, 0) to (n, n).
The key to this question: Record the location of both two snakes.
We define:
sol(k, x1, x2) is answer for a k steps trip
  , where snake1 is in point(x1, k - x1) and snake2 is in point(x2, k - x2)

So we have:
if x1 = x2 #snake in same location
  sol(k, x1, x2) = max(sol(k-1, x1, x2)
                       , sol(k-1, x1-1, x2)
                       , sol(k-1, x1, x2-1)
                       , sol(k-1, x1-1, x2-1))
                   + array[x1][k-x1]
else
  sol(k, x1, x2) = max(sol(k-1, x1, x2)
                       , sol(k-1, x1-1, x2)
                       , sol(k-1, x1, x2-1)
                       , sol(k-1, x1-1, x2-1))
                   + array[x1][k-x1] + array[x2][k-x2]


Then we can solve this problem by dynamic programming.
Also, we can find: No intersect in the optimal solution.
Because, if there is an intersection in a solution, we can find another solution that can cover a larger area without intersections.
The way is, let one snake go down instead of right to avoid any intersect, which can cover a larger area.
For example:
Blue grid for snake 1, green grid for snake 2, and cyan grid for if both snake walk through.
If we have the path:

Then we can change to:

That makes a larger cover area.
So, in our solution, we only cares about solution which x1 < x2(except the start and end point).
I write a Python code, and you check it for details:
def sol(array):
    mem = {}

    def _sol(k, x1, x2):
        y1 = k - x1
        y2 = k - x2
        if x1 < 0 or x2 < 0 or y1 < 0 or y2 < 0:
            return 0
        if x1 >= x2 and k != 0 and k != total_step:
            return 0
        if mem.get((k, x1, x2)) is not None:
            return mem[(k, x1, x2)]
        ans = 0
        if x1 == x2:
            ans += array[x1][y1]
        else:
            ans += array[x1][y1] + array[x2][y2]
        ans += max(_sol(k - 1, x1, x2), _sol(k - 1, x1 - 1, x2 - 1), _sol(k - 1, x1 - 1, x2), _sol(k - 1, x1, x2 - 1))
        mem[(k, x1, x2)] = ans
        return ans
    total_step = len(array) + len(array[0]) - 2
    x = len(array) - 1
    return _sol(total_step, x, x)


test = [
      [1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
    , [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    , [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    , [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    , [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

print(sol(test))


